# Approach to serialize cloud endpoint model class to Android file system

Tags: android, caching, serialization, google-cloud-endpoints

I have successfully created a cloud endpoint model that allows for easy retrieval of information from App Engine.  To reduce the roundtrips and provide a faster user experience, I have identified one instance I wish to store to local storage.

Throughout the rest of my app, I am using ObjectInputStream to read and write the objects such as:

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("PRIVFILE");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
AppModelState s = (AppModelState) ois.readObject();
```

This obviously requires all data members to implement the Serializable interface.  The Model class extends GenericJSON and is not "Serializable", as

```
    public final class ModelClass extends GenericJson {}
```

I could manually create a serializable object that maps to the model; however, that seems very amateur due to the number of attributes.

The other alternative I considered was creating a Serializable Object wrapper that simply has the JSON string as a member and provides a setter/getter accepting the ModelClass as parameters, such as:

```
class AppModelState implements Serializable {
   private String modelClassJSON;

   public ModelClass getModelClass() {
      // generate a new ModelClass from the JSON
   }

   public void setModelClass(ModelClass c) {
      // extract the JSON for storage
   }

   .....
}
```

I feel like there must be a better way and this should have been solved a dozen times but I am not finding any resources.  Please provide input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that doing standard Java serialization of classes that will be used with Endpoints doesn't work very well.  The problem is that serialization is binary, and HTTP comm is string.

If you were doing the HTTP comm yourself, rather then using endpoints, I think you would have the same problem.  In order to send the object you would serialize it (converting an string members to binary) and then you would have to convert the binary back to string.

So, if the amount of data you are using is not too much, it would probably be easiest to store your objects as JSON.

Answer (score 6):

I'm doing exactly the same as you say in your question.

Since Cloud Endpoints objects are already serialized for transmit over the wire, they are also serializable to be stored locally.  As an added bonus, with Android 3.0 or later, you don't even need to import any libraries -- it's already there!  For example:

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;

private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new AndroidJsonFactory();

public void putObject(String key, Object value) throws Exception {
    byte[] outputbytes = null;
    if (value instanceof GenericJson) {
        outputbytes = JSON_FACTORY.toByteArray(value);
    } else {
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectstream = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
        objectstream.writeObject(value);
        objectstream.close();
        outputbytes = output.toByteArray();
    }

    // persist "outputbytes" ...
}

public <T> T getObject(String key, Class<T> outclass) throws Exception {
    // retrieve saved bytes...
    byte[] valuebytes = ...

    if (valuebytes[0] == '{' && valuebytes[1] == '"' && valuebytes[valuebytes.length-1] == '}') {
        // Looks like JSON...
        return JSON_FACTORY.fromString(new String(valuebytes, "UTF-8"), outclass);
    } else {
        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(valuebytes);
        ObjectInputStream objectstream = new ObjectInputStream(input);
        Object value = objectstream.readObject();
        objectstream.close();
        return outclass.cast(value);
    }
}
```

Note that the default `AndroidJsonFactory` (as of Android v4.3, anyway) is quite slow when serializing long strings.  Create a new `JacksonFactory` instead if you have performance problems.  Everything else stays the same.

**Update:**  If you want to serialize a list of GenericJson objects, you just have to create a GenericJson object that includes a list of those objects.  For example:

```
import com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson;
import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

public static class PersistantJson extends GenericJson {
    @Key public int one;
    @Key public String two;
}

public static class PersistantJsonList extends GenericJson {
    @Key public List<PersistantJson> list = new ArrayList<PersistantJson>();
}
```

You can now add all your `PersistantJson` (i.e. some class created by "generate cloud endpoint client library") objects to the `.list` element of a `PersistantJsonList` variable and then pass that variable to `putObject()`.  Note that this requires all objects in the list to be of the same class so that deserialization knows what the type is (because JSON serialization does not record the type).  If you use `List<Object>` then what is read back is a `List<Map<String, Object>>` and you have to extract the fields manually.

Comment: @Brain do you know a way to deserialize a **list** of Cloud Endpoints objects ?

Comment: @AsafK, that's a good question.  I hadn't tried to do so and had to play a bit to get it to work.  I've updated my answer with what I found.  If your cloud-endpoint library includes an object that is a list of other objects then I think it will already "just work" (though I haven't tried it).